# Scala using map after a groupBy

Tags: scala, dictionary, group-by

Given this code

```
val list = List(
    Person("John", "Paris", 1956);
    Person("Jane", "London", 1954);
    Person("James", "Paris", 1972);
    Person("Marie", "London", 1959);
)
```

I want to create a map(key->value), in which the key is the city, and the value is the average age of the persons living in that city.

I have used the groupBy method :

```
val groupedByCity = list.groupBy(_.city);
```

Which give me this :

```
Map(Paris -> List(Person(Jonh, Paris, 1956), Person(James, Paris, 1972)), London -> List( Person(Jane, London, 1954), Person(Marie, London, 1959)));
```

How can I remap this to filter the information I need, which is the average age by city ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.mapValues` on the map, with a function, whose argument will be a list of persons for the city. Inside that function, use `.map` to make it into list of ages, then `.sum` to compute the total, and divide by the the size of the list.

Comment: I think i made it ! Thank you for your help.

Here is how I did : 

 `code` val averageAgeByCity = groupedByCity.mapValues( p => p.map(2014-_.birth).sum/p.size); `code`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one pass using

```
 groupedByCity.mapValues( p => (0.0 /: p){_ + 2014 - _.age} / p.length)
   }                                             
 //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(Paris -> 50.0, London -> 57.5)
```